# can we implement polymorphism using interface in c#?

Tags: c#, interface

can we implement polymorphism using interface in c#? any example .

Comment: What do you mean by "polymorphism" in this context?  An interface by it's very nature enables polymorphism since you can pass any class that implements it wherever the interface is expected.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes.

E.g. See the way many collections in the framework implement `IList<T>` so code that only depends on that interface can use any of those collections.